# Make request (pass data) from Command File to Controller in Lumen/Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, request, lumen, dispatch

i get data (query) in command file and want to pass to controller via API (route)

here my request code in command file :

```
$request = Request::create('/create_data_account', 'post', ['data'=>$data]);
$create = $app->dispatch($request);
```

this is the route :

```
$router->post('/create_data_account', 'APIController@create_account_data_api');
```

and my controller :

```
 public function create_account_data_api(Request $request)
    {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $insert = Account::create([
                                'account_name'  => $value->account_name,
                                'type'          => $value->type,
                                'role_id'       => $value->role_id
                            ]);
            if($insert){
                $count++;
            }else{
                return $response = ['result'=>false, 'count'=>$count, 'message'=>'Internal error. Failed to save data.']; 
            }
        }
        return $response = ['result'=>true, 'count'=>$count, 'message'=>'Account data saved Successfully'];
    }
```

i'm confused why passing data to controller not working with that code. anyone can give me solution ? Thanks

Comment: theses data send to the request object try to print your `$request` and you will find your data like this `$request->all()`

Comment: @Joseph i didn't get any error, but my data still failed send to controller

Answer (score 0):

As you are making the request with `['data'=>$data]`. That means all the data is contained on the key `data` of your array. So before the **foreach** loop, you need to add a declaration statement `$data = $request->input('data');` to get data in `$data` variable.

Comment: On the very first line, `$request = Request::create('/create_data_account', 'post', ['data'=>$data]);`, does the `$data` has some value? Try with `['data' => ['some', 'test', 'data']]`